# Ordering column by late merge method

Tags: postgresql

I do have a table A with a column col1. The elements in this column should get a new arrangement. The first element is the first, the last element become the second, the second element become the third and so on...

```
col1                                   col1
----                                   -----
 1                                       1
 2                                       5
 3           result =>                   2
 4                                       4
 5                                       3
```

For my it looks like a [late merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(traffic)). How to apply a late merge in my case?

1. Add a column in reverse order

   ```
     col1   col2
     ------  -----
      1        4
      2        3
      3        2
      4        1
   ```
2. Merge them into one column
3. Delete all records where row_number() > last_index/2

Comment: I believe your question is clear enough. Actually, you don't seem to be asking anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have monotonically increasing `col1` values like in your example. In a regular query, it would work like this:

```
SELECT col1,
       CASE WHEN col1 <= (max + 1) / 2 THEN col1 * 2 - 1 
                                       ELSE (max - col1 + 1) * 2
       END AS col2
FROM t,
     (SELECT max(col1) max FROM t) m;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/85360/3)

In an `UPDATE` statement, you would do this:

```
UPDATE t
SET col1 = CASE WHEN col1 <= (max + 1) / 2 THEN col1 * 2 - 1 
                                           ELSE (max - col1 + 1) * 2
           END
FROM (SELECT max(col1) max FROM t) m;
```